# Database structure and calculated rows

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

### Some background

I'm building a bit of a shopping cart. Certain products (not all) are redeemable as indicated by the `redeemable` field in the `products` table.

When a product is redeemed, the `redeemed_qty` and `location_id` are set as a row in the `line_item_states` table. This allows two things:

1. Although a product originally has a location, once redeemed we can set a new location for the redeemed qty
2. You can redeem a purchased product multiple times (up to the total purchase quantity)

### The issue

I'm trying to create a report that will list all the `line_items` but enhanced/expanded by `line_item_states`.

For example, given the data below, it should list the LineItem 3 times:

```
Product               | Redeemed? | Qty | Location
Full Yard Landscaping | No        | 4   | 2
Full Yard Landscaping | Yes       | 8   | 3
Full Yard Landscaping | Yes       | 2   | 1
```

It's listed 3 times because the `line_item_states` for that `line_item` are grouped by location with their `redeemed_qty` summed.

I'm able to achieve the above table BUT without the first row. That is the row with the calculated remaining unredeemed qty. So basically a virtual row of some sorts?

This is my current query to generate the above table (without the first row):

```
LineItem.select('"line_items".*,
        COALESCE("locs"."location_id", "products"."location_id") "location_id",   
        COALESCE("locs"."rqty", "line_items"."qty") "lqty",
        "locs"."rqty" "qty_redeemed"')
.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT "lie"."line_item_id",
                    "lie"."location_id",
                    SUM("lie"."redeemed_qty") "rqty"
             FROM "line_item_states" "lie"
             GROUP BY "lie"."line_item_id", "lie"."location_id") "locs"
          ON ("line_items"."id" = "locs"."line_item_id")
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "products"
          ON "products"."id" = "line_items"."product_id"')
```

### Question

How to I expand the query to also generate that first row in the example table?
Is it even possible? Am I looking at this the wrong way?

---

### Information and sample data

#### Data

**LineItem:**

```
#<LineItem id: 24, order_id: 19, product_id: 3, created_at: "2014-08-20 01:27:53", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:51:51", qty: 14, discount: #<BigDecimal:7ff0ba69e238,'0.0',9(18)>, discount_type: nil, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff0ba69e0f8,'0.1069E3',18(18)>, total: #<BigDecimal:7ff0ba69e030,'0.14966E4',18(18)>>
```

**Product:**

```
#<Product id: 3, title: "Full Yard Landscaping", full_price: #<BigDecimal:7ff0ba4d6400,'0.299E3',9(18)>, created_at: "2014-08-18 02:23:25", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:50:56", price_overridable: true, deposit_price: #<BigDecimal:7ff0ba4d5910,'0.11E3',9(18)>, gvable: true, redeemable: true, location_id: 2>
```

**LineItemState:**

```
[#<LineItemState id: 51, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:26:33", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:26:33", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 52, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:26:56", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:26:56", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 53, redeemed_qty: 2, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:30:30", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:30:30", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 54, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:31:08", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:31:08", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 55, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:31:22", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:31:22", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 56, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:31:59", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:31:59", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 57, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 05:58:21", updated_at: "2014-08-21 05:58:21", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 58, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 06:03:34", updated_at: "2014-08-21 06:03:34", line_item_id: 24, notes: nil>,
 #<LineItemState id: 59, redeemed_qty: 1, location_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-21 06:04:20", updated_at: "2014-08-21 06:04:20", line_item_id: 24, notes: "Another cool message dude!">]
```

#### Product

**Schema**

```
create_table "products", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.decimal  "full_price",        precision: 7, scale: 2, default: 0.0
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "price_overridable",                         default: false
  t.decimal  "deposit_price",     precision: 7, scale: 2, default: 0.0
  t.boolean  "gvable",                                    default: false
  t.boolean  "redeemable",                                default: false
  t.integer  "location_id"
end
```

**Model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  belongs_to :location
end
```

#### LineItem

**Schema**

```
  create_table "line_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "qty",           limit: 8,                         default: 1
    t.decimal  "discount",                precision: 7, scale: 2, default: 0.0
    t.string   "discount_type"
    t.decimal  "price",                   precision: 7, scale: 2, default: 0.0
    t.decimal  "total",                   precision: 7, scale: 2, default: 0.0
  end
```

**Model**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :line_item_states
end
```

#### LineItemState

**Schema**

```
create_table "line_item_states", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "redeemed_qty"
  t.integer  "location_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "line_item_id"
  t.text     "notes"
end
```

**Model**

```
class LineItemState < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Comment: Your query contradicts the displayed output. Please edit to make it coherent.

Comment: Hey @ErwinBrandstetter, how does it contradict the output? That's the query I'm using. Of course I'm selecting more fields than I'm displaying but otherwise it's accurate.

Comment: Your output has the columns `Product | Redeemed? | Qty | Location`, which is *not* what the displayed query returns. Just make it unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) where you calculate redeemed quantities. In the main query used to subtract from the basic quantities and append the calculated rows with a `UNION ALL`.

With a basic set of columns the query could look like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT line_item_id, location_id, SUM(redeemed_qty) AS qty
   FROM   line_item_states
   GROUP  BY line_item_id, location_id
   )

SELECT FALSE AS redeemed, li.id AS line_item_id, li.location_id
      ,CASE WHEN r.qty IS NULL THEN li.qty ELSE li.qty - r.qty END AS qty
FROM   line_items li
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT line_item_id, sum(qty) AS qty
   FROM   cte
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r ON r.line_item_id = li.id

UNION  ALL
SELECT TRUE, c.line_item_id, COALESCE(c.location_id, p.location_id), c.qty
FROM   cte c
JOIN   line_items    li ON li.id = l.line_item_id 
LEFT   JOIN products p  ON p.id = li.product_id;
```

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter, I didn't know about CTEs so this definitely addresses the situation. I have however decided to go back and create a parent/child line-item situation in order to simplify queries.